# An inequality problem.

Tags: analysis, inequality

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Showing the inequality $|\alpha + \beta|^p \leq 2^{p-1}(|\alpha|^p + |\beta|^p)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/143173/showing-the-inequality-alpha-betap-leq-2p-1-alphap-betap)

In the condition $a,b \in[0,\infty)$, $1\le p<\infty$,

How can I conclude this inequality?
$$(a+b)^p \le 2^{p-1} (a^p + b^p)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could solve it using Hölder inequality.
$ (a+b)^p \leq 2^{p-1}(a^p+b^p) \Leftrightarrow
(a+b) \leq (1+1)^{1- \frac{1}{p}} (a^p +b^p)^{\frac{1}{p}} $
and then apply Hölder.

Comment: @ ckark : I prefer that the $\Rightarrow$ be replaced by $\Leftarrow$. Ins'nt it ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that inequality but it seems to be very useful.

Comment: way right! It could be replaced with a $ \Rightleftarrow $ also :D

Comment: hmm propably better $\Leftarrow$ but I will not change it again

Comment: sorry I rushed before, the inequality is $\sum_{i=0}^{n}a_i b_i   \leq  =(\sum_{i=0}^{n}a_i^q )^{\frac{1}{q}}(\sum_{i=0}^{n} b_i^p)^{\frac{1}{p}}$ where $\frac{1}{q} + \frac{1}{p}=1$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**   $f(x)=x^p$  and  convexity

$f(\frac a2  +  \frac  b2)  \leq   \frac 12 f(a)   +  \frac 12 f(b)$

Comment: Then can I conclude inequality by induction?

Comment: @ wowhapjs You hav'nt $p$ an integer. You replace $f\left(\frac{a+b}{2} \right)$ by it's value : $\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)^p$ and the same for $f(a)=a^p$ and $f(b)=b^p$ and you have the result