# How to prove$|a-b|^p\leq \max(1,2^{p-1})(|a|^p+|b|^P)$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I am stuck with this question:
How to prove$|a-b|^p\leq \max(1,2^{p-1})(|a|^p+|b|^p)$

I forgot to say a ,b are both complex number

Comment: Could you clarify what $a$, $b$ and $p$ are?  I'm guessing $a$ and $b$ are complex numbers (from the tags), and $p$ is an integer?

Comment: a,b are complex number and $0<p<\infty$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$p \geq 1$ is addressed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/143173/showing-the-inequality-alpha-betap-leq-2p-1-alphap-betap/143188#143188). For $p < 1$, and assuming that $a \geq b$, set $t = a/b>1$. Then we want to prove that
$$(t+1)^p \leq t^p + 1$$
$$f(t) = t^p + 1 - (t+1)^p \implies f'(t) = p\left(t^{p-1} - (t+1)^{p-1} \right) > 0$$
Hence, we get that $$t^p + 1 - (t+1)^p \geq f(0) = 0$$ This proves it for $p < 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Without loss of generality, suppose $a > b$, and let $c = a - b$ and use the binomial theorem.