# Motivation for the definition of weak solutions to parabolic equations of second order

Tags: partial-differential-equations, proof-explanation, parabolic-pde

I'm reading Evans' book about PDEs by myself and I'm trying understand the motivation for the definition of weak solutions  to parabolic equations of second order on pages $373$ and $374$.

First, we do preliminary assumptions:

> $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is an open bounded set and $U_T := U \times (0,T]$ for some fixed $T > 0$.
>
> We will first study the initial/boundary-value problem
>
> $$(1) \begin{cases} u_t + Lu = f \ \text{in} \ U_T\\
> u = 0 \ \text{on} \ \partial U \times [0,T]\\
> u = g \ \text{on} \ U \times \{ t = 0 \}  \end{cases}.$$
>
> The letter $L$ denotes for each time $t$ a second order partial differential operator , having the divergence form
>
> $$(2) \ Lu = - \sum_{i,j=1}^n (a^{ij}(x,t)u_{x_i})_{x_j} + \sum_{i=1}^n b^i u_{x_i} + c(x,t)u.$$
>
> $\textbf{b. Weak solutions.}$ Mimicking the developments in $\S 6.1.2$ for elliptic equations, we consider first the case that $L$ has divergence form $(2)$ and try to find an appropriate notion of weak solution for the initial/boundary-value problem $(1)$. We assume for now that
>
> \begin{align*} (5) \ a^{ij}, b^i, c &\in L^{\infty} (U_T) \ (i,j = 1, \cdots, n)\\
> (6) \ f &\in L^2(U_T),\\
> (7) \ g &\in L^2(U) \end{align*}
>
> We also suppose $a^{ij} = a^{ji} \ (i,j = 1, \cdots, n)$.
>
> Let us now define, by analogy with the notation introduced in Chapter $6$, the time-dependent bilinear form
>
> $$(8) \ B[u,v;t] := \int_U \sum_{i,j=1}^n a^{ij}(\cdot,t) u_{x_i}v_{x_j} + \sum_{i=1}^n b^i(\cdot, t) u_{x_i} v + c(\cdot,t)uv dx$$
>
> for $u,v \in H^1_0(U)$ and a.e. $0 \leq t \leq T$.

Now, the motivation:

> $\textbf{Motivation for definition of weak solution.}$ To make plausible the following definition of weak solution, let us first temporarily suppose that $u = u(x,t)$ is in fact a smooth solution in parabolic setting of our problem $(1)$. We know switch our pointview, by associating with $u$ a mapping
>
> $$\textbf{u}: [0,T] \longrightarrow H^1_0(U)$$
>
> defined by
>
> $$[\textbf{u}(t)](x) := u(x,t) \ (x \in U, 0 \leq t \leq T).$$
>
> In other words, we are going consider $u$ not as a function of $x$ and $t$ together, but rather as a mapping  $\textbf{u}$ of $t$  into the space $H^1_0(U)$ of functions of $x$. This point of view will greatly clarify the following presentation.
>
> Returning to the problem $(1)$, let us similary define
>
> $$\textbf{f}: [0,T] \longrightarrow L^2(U)$$
>
> by
>
> $$[\textbf{f}(t)](x) := f(x,t) \ (x \in U, 0 \leq t \leq T).$$
>
> Then if we fix a function $v \in H^1_0(U)$, we can multiply the PDE $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} + Lu = f$ by $v$ and integrate by parts to find
>
> $$(9) \ (\textbf{u}',v) + B[\textbf{u},v;t] = (\textbf{f},v) \ \left( ' = \frac{d}{dt} \right)$$
>
> for each $0 \leq t \leq T$, the pairing $(,)$ denoting the inner product of $L^2(U)$. Next, observe that
>
> $$(10) \ u_t = g^0 + \sum_{j=1}^n g^j_{x_j} \ \text{in} \ U_T$$
>
> for $g^0 := f - \sum_{i=1}^n b^i u_{x_i} - cu$ and $g^j := \sum_{i=1}^n a^{ij}u_{x_i}$ $(j = 1, \cdots, n)$. Consequently and the definitions from $\S 5.9.1$ imply the right-hand side of $(10)$ lies in the Sobolev space $H^{-1}(U)$, with
>
> $$||u_t||_{H^{-1}(U)} \leq \left( \sum_{j=1}^n ||g^j||^2_{L^2(U)} \right)^{\frac{1}{2}} \leq C \left( ||u||_{H^1_0(U)} + ||f||_{L^2(U)} \right).$$
>
> This estimate suggests it may be reasonable to look for weak solution with $\textbf{u}' \in H^{-1}(U)$ for a.e $0 \leq t \leq T$ , in which case the first term in $(9)$ can be reexpressed as $\langle \textbf{u}',v \rangle$, $\langle , \rangle$ being the pairing of $H^{-1}(U)$ and $H^1_0(U)$.

My doubt is how the inequalities above are obtained? I can't see how derive them since we not suppose $\textbf{u}' \in H^{-1}(U)$ and, therefore, we can't use the result from $\S 5.9.1$, which is a caracterization of the space $H^{-1}$.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea of the motivation is to conclude that $\mathbf{u}'\in H^{-1}(U)$ instead of take it as an assumption.

Equality (10) shows that $u_t\in L^2(U)\subset H^{-1}(U)$ and thus the first inequality follows from §5.9.1. Then $\mathbf{u}'(t)\in H^{-1}(U)$ (for each $t$) because $[\mathbf{u}'(t)](x)=u_t(t,x)$.

### Edit

From the definition of $g^0$,
$$\begin{align*}
\|g^0\|_{L^2(U)} &= \left\|f - \sum_{i=1}^n b^i u_{x_i} - cu\right\|_{L^2(U)}\\
&\leq\|f\|_{L^2(U)}+\sum_{i=1}^n\|b^i\|_{L^\infty(U)}\|u_{x_i}\|_{L^2(U)}+\|c\|_{L^\infty(U)}\|u\|_{L^2(U)}\\
&\leq \|f\|_{L^2(U)}+c_0\sum_{i=1}^n\|u_{x_i}\|_{L^2(U)}+c_1\|u\|_{L^2(U)}\\
&\leq \|f\|_{L^2(U)}+c_2\|u\|_{H_0^1(U)}\\\end{align*}$$
and thus
$$\|g^0\|_{L^2(U)}^2\leq c_3\left(\|f\|_{L^2(U)}+\|u\|_{H_0^1(U)}\right)^2.$$
Analogously, from the definition of $g^j$,
$$\begin{align*}
\|g^j\|_{L^2(U)}^2 &=\left\| \sum_{i=1}^n a^{ij}u_{x_i}\right\|_{L^2(U)}^2\\
&\leq\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\|a^{ij}\|_{L^\infty}\left\|  u_{x_i}\right\|_{L^2(U)}\right)^2\\
&\leq \left(\sum_{i=1}^nc_4\left\|  u_{x_i}\right\|_{L^2(U)}\right)^2\\
&\leq c_5\sum_{i=1}^n\left\|  u_{x_i}\right\|_{L^2(U)}^2\\
&\leq c_5\|  u\|_{H_0^1(U)}^2\\
&\leq c_5(\|f\|_{L^2(U)}+\|u\|_{H_0^1(U)})^2.
\end{align*}$$
Therefore,
$$\begin{align*}
\|u_t\|_{H^{-1}(U)} &\leq \left( \sum_{j=0}^n \|g^j\|^2_{L^2(U)} \right)^{\frac{1}{2}} \\
&\leq \left( \sum_{j=1}^n c_6\left(\|f\|_{L^2(U)}+\|u\|_{H_0^1(U)}\right)^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}} \\
&\leq C\left(\|f\|_{L^2(U)}+\|u\|_{H_0^1(U)}\right)
\end{align*}$$

### Edit 2

For the first inequality in your comment, note that
$$\begin{align*}
& \|u\|_{H_0^1}=\left(\|u\|_{L^2}^2+\|u_{x_1}\|_{L^2}^2+\cdots+\|u_{x_n}\|_{L^2}^2\right)^{1/2}\\
\Longrightarrow\qquad &\|u\|_{H_0^1}^2=\|u\|_{L^2}^2+\|u_{x_1}\|_{L^2}^2+\cdots+\|u_{x_n}\|_{L^2}^2\\
\Longrightarrow\qquad &\|u\|_{H_0^1}^2\geq\|u\|_{L^2}^2\quad\text{and}\quad \|u\|_{H_0^1}^2\geq\|u_{x_j}\|_{L^2}^2\;(j=1,...,n)\\
\Longrightarrow\qquad &\|u\|_{L^2}\leq \|u\|_{H_0^1}\quad\text{and}\quad \|u_{x_j}\|_{L^2}\leq \|u\|_{H_0^1}\;(j=1,...,n)\\
\Longrightarrow\qquad &c_0\sum_{i=1}^n\|u_{x_i}\|_{L^2}+c_1\|u\|_{L^2}
\leq c_0 \sum_{i=1}^n\|u\|_{H_0^1}+c_1\|u\|_{H_0^1}=(nc_0+c_1)\|u\|_{H_0^1}
\end{align*}$$
For the second, note that (as proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/222431/how-to-provea-bp-leq-max1-2p-1apbp)) if $x_1,...,x_n\geq 0$ and $p>0$, then there exists a constant $k$ (which depends on $p$ and $n$) such that
$$(x_1+\cdots+x_n)^p\leq k(x_1^p+\cdots +x_n^p).$$

Comment: Ok, I understand now how can the first inequality was obtained, but how the second inequality was obtained? The closest thing that I could think is use the theorem $3$ of $\S 5.9.2$, but this theorem states that if $\textbf{u} \in L^2(0,T;H^1_0(U))$ with $\textbf{u}' \in L^2(0,T;H^{-1}(U))$, then

$$\max_{0 \leq t \leq T} ||\textbf{u}(t)||_{L^2(U)} \leq C \left( ||\textbf{u}||_{L^2(0,T;H^1_0(U))} + ||\textbf{u}'||_{L^2(0,T;H^{-1}(U))} \right),$$

the constant depending only on $T$, but I think this isn't help me since the estimative doesn't have $||f||_{L^2(U)}$.

Comment: @George For the second inequality, see my edit.

Comment: I didn't understand the following inequalities in your edit:

$$1. \|f\|_{L^2(U)}+c_0\sum_{i=1}^n\|u_{x_i}\|_{L^2(U)}+c_1\|u\|_{L^2(U)} \leq \|f\|_{L^2(U)}+c_2\|u\|_{H_0^1(U)}$$

$$2. \left(\sum_{i=1}^nc_4\left\|  u_{x_i}\right\|_{L^2(U)}\right)^2 \leq c_5\sum_{i=1}^n\left\|  u_{x_i}\right\|_{L^2(U)}^2$$

I didn't understand the first inequality, because $|| \cdot ||_{H^1_0(U)} = || \cdot ||_{W^{1,2}(U)}$ and this norm involves the square root of the sum of the square of $L^2$-norms of $u$ and its weak derivatives of order $1$, but you only have the sum of these $L^2$-norms.

Comment: While the first inequality I imagine that it's an inequality of real numbers like this:

$$\left( \sum_{i=1}^n a_i \right)^2 \leq \sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2$$

with $a_i > 0$ real numbers for each $i = 1, \cdots, n$, but I can't see why this is true

Comment: @George See my Edit 2.

Comment: Thanks for share the proof for the second inequality, it is indeed very hepful in the future for me. I see a sometimes this kind of inequality in other contexts, but I never understood, because I didn't sure if the inequality was true, but I didn't not imagine that this inequality is true for a real power $p$ arbitrary

Comment: @George You are welcome. Yes, that inequality is really useful in the context of pdes. Note that $k$ does not depend only on $p$ (as I said in my original second edit). It also depends on $n$ (because that, for $n\geq 3$ factors, we have to apply the original inequality in the link $n-1$ times).

Comment: @Pedro Can you explain why the estimation for $u_t$ suggest it may be reasonable to look for weak solution with $u_t\in H^{−1}$? What is the relationship between the estimation and the space to look for weak solution?

Comment: @BBIN The reasonable regularity for $u$ and $f$ in (9), as a weak formulation of (1), is $u\in L^2(0,T;H^1_0)$ and $f\in L^2(0,T;L^2)$. And the estimate implies (by integrating both sides on $[0,T]$) that $u'\in L^2(0,T; H^{-1})$ provided that this reasonable regularity for $u$ and $f$ is satisfied. For example: if we have the estimate $\|u'\|_{H^{-1}}\geq \frac{C}{t}$, it is not reasonable to expect that there exists a solutin $u$ such that $u'\in L^2(0,T;H^{-1})$ because $t\mapsto \|u'\|_{H^{-1}}^2$ is not integrable. This is how I understood it.