# Finiteness of absolute moments

Tags: probability-theory

If $r>0$ then why is it that $E(|X|^r)<\infty$ if and only if $E(|X-a|^r)<\infty$ for every $a$. In the simplified case of a probability distribution describing $X$ then it says that

$$\int |x|^rp(x)dx <\infty \leftrightarrow \int |x-a|^r p(x)dx<\infty$$

But why should that be true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything follows from the inequalities 
$$|x+a|^r\leqslant (|x|+|a|)^r\leqslant \max\{1,2^{r-1}\}\cdot(|x|^r+|a|^r),$$
where the second inequality follows from [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/143173/showing-the-inequality-alpha-betap-leq-2p-1-alphap-betap/143183#143183) when $r\geqslant 1$ and concavity of $x\mapsto |x|^r$ if $0<r<1$.

Comment: Wait I don't see how it follows from concavity when $0<r<1$.

Comment: I figured out that for the case of $0<r<1$ it works to integrate $|x|^{r-1} - |x+a|^{r-1} > 0$.