# How to prove this inequality by using induction?

Tags: induction

If $x,y$ are distinct real numbers such that $x+y>0$ and $n\ge 1$, then $2^{n-1}(x^n+y^n)\ge (x+y)^n$.

It is obvious for $n=1$. How to do the rest by using induction?

Comment: This is true for any $n \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 1}$. See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/143173/showing-the-inequality-alpha-betap-leq-2p-1-alphap-betap/143188#143188). If you are just looking for a proof and not by induction, I would vote to close this down as duplicate of the other.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose the claim is true for $n$. Then, multiply $2^{n-1}(x^{n}+y^{n})\ge (x+y)^n$ by $(x+y)$ on both sides to obtain (note that here we are using $x+y>0$)
$$ 2^{n-1}(x^{n}+y^{n})(x+y) \ge (x+y)^{n+1}$$
To prove the inductive hypothesis it is enough to show that
$$ 2^{n}(x^{n+1}+y^{n+1}) \ge 2^{n-1}(x^{n}+y^{n})(x+y)$$
which boils down to proving (I will let you proceed the intermediate steps on your own):
$$ x^{n+1}+y^{n+1}\ge x^n y + xy^{n}$$
Without loss of generality, assume $x\ge y$. Then:
$$ x^{n+1}+y^{n+1}-x^{n}y-xy^{n}=(x^{n}-y^{n})(x-y)\ge 0$$
as desired.

**Edit:** as pointed out by Ross Millikan, we do not need the assumption that $x$ and $y$ are distinct.

Comment: Just wondering, how is it that you can claim $x\ne y$ and not lose generality?

Comment: @anorton: It says in the question that $x$ and $y$ are distinct.

Comment: @anorton:  since the comparisons are $\ge$ it works fine if $x=y$.  The two sides are equal then.

Comment: @anorton Ooopss: sorry I meant $x>y$. Thanks! Corrected.

Comment: @Prism:  But the request was $\ge$ and, as you said, $x \neq y$ was specified.  It works both ways.  You can change yours to $\gt$ if you want.

Comment: @RossMillikan: Thanks. I have edited it accordingly.

Comment: How do you know that $x^n-y^n\ge 0$?

Comment: @user73564 Suppose $y$ were negative, then the condition $x+y>0$ implies $0<|y|<x$, so that $x^n\ge |y|^n\ge y^n$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** convexity of $f\colon t\in\mathbb{R}_+\mapsto t^n$.

Observe that the result is equivalent to 
$$
\frac{x^n+y^n}{2} \geq \left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)^n
$$
that is
$$
\frac{f(x)+f(y)}{2} \geq f\!\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)
$$

However, this method does not rely on induction.

---

For one with induction: assume the result is known for $n\geq 1$:
$$
\frac{x^n+y^n}{2} \geq \left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)^n
$$
Then (as $x+y>0$)
$$
\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)^{n+1} \leq \frac{x+y}{2}\cdot\frac{x^n+y^n}{2} =
\frac{x^{n+1}+y^{n+1}+xy^n+yx^n}{4}
$$
Remains to prove that
$$
\frac{x^{n+1}+y^{n+1}+xy^n+yx^n}{4} \leq\frac{2x^{n+1}+2y^{n+1}}{4}
$$
i.e. that
$$
x^{n+1}+y^{n+1} - (xy^n+yx^n) \geq 0
$$
But the LHS can be rewritten
$$
x^{n+1}+y^{n+1} - (xy^n+yx^n) = (x^{n}-y^{n}) (x-y)
$$
which is indeed always positive as $x+y>0$ (whether $x>y$ or $y>x$, at least one of them is positive; a further analysis shows that, independently of the parity of $n$, both factors will have the same sign).

Comment: I corrected what I think was a typo.

Comment: Oops. I might have overwritten your change — what was it?

Comment: You wrote $$\frac{f(x^n)+f(y^n)}{2} $$ instead of $$\frac{f(x)+f(y)}{2} $$

Comment: Oh, yes — thanks.