# Classic $c_r$-inequality in $l_r$ space: $E(|X+Y|^r)\leq c_r[E(|X|^r)+E(|Y|^r)]$

Tags: probability, inequality

> How does one prove:
>   $$
> E(|X+Y|^r)\leq c_r\bigg[E(|X|^r)+E(|Y|^r)\bigg]
> $$
>   where $c_r=1$ if $0<r\leq 1$ and $2^{r-1}$ if $r>1$?

This is a classic result whose proof I once knew but have since forgotten. Can someone please explain so I could learn it again? Thank you.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/143173/showing-the-inequality-alpha-betap-leq-2p-1-alphap-betap.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For $a,b\geqslant 0$, show and use the inequalities 
$$(a+b)^r\leqslant a^r+b^r\mbox{ if }0\lt r\leqslant 1   $$
and 
$$(a+b)^r\leqslant 2^{r-1}(a^r+b^r)\mbox{ if }r\gt1.$$

This uses concavity (for $r\leqslant 1$) and convexity (for $r\gt 1$) of the function $t\mapsto t^r$.