# Convexity of $x^{2q}$ implies $\mathbb{E} \big[ \left(X-X^{'}\right)^{2q} \big]\leq 2^{2q-1} \left( \mathbb{E}X^{2q}+ \mathbb{E}X^{'2q} \right) $

Tags: probability, inequality, convexity-inequality

This problem is from page 25 of [concentration inequalities a nonasymptotic theory of independence](https://www.hse.ru/data/2016/11/24/1113029206/Concentration%20inequalities.pdf)

$X$ is a random variable
and $X^{'}$ is independent copy of $X$

q is integer and $q\geq1$

It is said that the following inequality was implied by the convexity of $x^{2q}$

$$\mathbb{E} \big[ \left(X-X^{'}\right)^{2q} \big]\leq 2^{2q-1} \left( \mathbb{E}X^{2q}+ \mathbb{E}X^{'2q} \right) $$

However, I do not know how to deduce it. The first guess is using Minkowski inequality to get terms of $\mathbb{E}X^{2q}$ and  $\mathbb{E}X^{'2q}$. The Jensen ineqaulity will give inequality of reverse direction, I am wondering how convexity is applied. Any suggestion is welcomed.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1102727/classic-c-r-inequality-in-l-r-space-exyr-leq-c-rexreyr

Comment: Thx. I am wondering how $$(a+b)^r\leqslant a^r+b^r\mbox{ if }0\lt r\leqslant 1 $$ is deduced from concavity of $ x^r$. I can see it throguh Bernoulli inequality but it's fine to find a unified way to do it through Jensen's inequality.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/318649/square-root-of-a-sum-bound