# Holder inequality in proving sobolev interpolation inequality

Tags: inequality, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

I am reading the book "Elliptic Partial Differential Equations of Second Order" by D. Gilbarg and N.S. Trudinger.

In theorem 7.27, it stated that after we obtained 
$$|u'(x)| \leq \int_{a}^{b}|u''| + \frac{18}{\epsilon^2}\int|u|,$$
we can apply Holder's inequality to get
$$|u'(x)|^p \leq 2^{p-1}\left\{ \epsilon^{p-1}\int_{a}^{b}|u''|^p + \frac{(18)^p}{\epsilon^{p+1}}\int_{a}^{b}|u|^p \right\}.$$

I am wondering how Holder's inequality is used to get the second inequality.

Answer (score 1):

In that proof, $\epsilon=b-a$. So,

$$\begin{align}
\int_{a}^{b}|u''|&=\int_{a}^{b}|1\cdot u''|\\
&\leq\left(\int_{a}^{b}|1|^q\right)^{1/q}\left(\int_{a}^{b}|u''|^p\right)^{1/p}\\
&=(b-a)^{1/q}\left(\int_{a}^{b}|u''|^p\right)^{1/p}\\
&=\epsilon^{(p-1)/p}\left(\int_{a}^{b}|u''|^p\right)^{1/p}
\end{align}$$

Now, do a similar calculation for the integral

$$\frac{18}{\epsilon^2}\int|u|=\frac{1}{\epsilon^2}\int|1\cdot 18u|,$$

take the power $p$ and use the inequality [$$(a+b)^p\leq 2^{p-1}(a^p+b^p).$$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/143173/showing-the-inequality-alpha-betap-leq-2p-1-alphap-betap)

Comment: I get it now. Thank you very much!