# Upper bound for the sum $\left|\sum_{i=1}^N x_i\right|^p$

Tags: combinatorics, inequality, multinomial-coefficients

Since it is a simple looking question, this might be asked before (however I was not able to find it).

I am looking for a bound in the form,
$$\left|\sum_{i=1}^N x_i\right|^p \leq C(p,N) \sum_{i=1}^N |x_i|^p$$ for $x_i\in\mathbb{R}$, with an **explicit constant** $C(p,N)$ (at least with its dependence to $N$). I would be very happy if I could learn the order of $C(p,N)$ in terms of $N$ (or $N,p$ together).

There is a [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/143173/showing-the-inequality-alpha-betap-leq-2p-1-alphap-betap) in math.SE for $N = 2$ case, where $C(p,N) = 2^{p-1}$. In general, I am interested in this constant for general $N$.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean
$$$$if $p\ge 1$ then
$$
\\\left|\dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^N x_i}{N}\right|^p\le\dfrac{\left|\sum_{i=1}^N |x_i|^p\right|}{N}
\\C(p, N)=N^{p-1}
$$

Comment: I believe the generalized mean is for non-negative $x_i$ only.